# Getting latitude and longitude of vertices/corner points of polygon/building from online maps such as OpenStreetMap?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, josm

I have tried using JOSM(Java OpenStreetMap) and QGIS for directly getting latitude and longitude of vertices/corner points of polygon/building but I am unable to get.

Is there any way to get?

Comment: Did you try Extract nodes from the vector menu? You have the info in the info sidebar or you could extract it into fields via the field calculator.

Comment: Have you considered using Overpass Turbo with 'out geometry' to get the coordinates. A google search should bring up good options. Sorry can't provide more info now.